# Using twilio api for making phone to phone calls?

Tags: android, api, twilio, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-php

Can I make Phone to Phone call using Twilio api?
I don't want to use internet connection for making this call but I want to use Twilio api as well..
Is there a way for doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

Sounds like you want to let one user call a standard PSTN phone number and then bridge that call to another PSTN phone?

If I've got that right you can do that by using the [`<Dial>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial).  When the caller dials your Twilio number, Twilio is going to make an HTTP request to whatever URL you have configured as the Voice URL for that phone number.  That URL can return TwiML that looks like this:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>+15555555555</Dial>
</Response>
```

This tells Twilio to take the inbound call and bridge it with an outbound call to the number specified by the Dial verb.

Hope that helps.